# Storing data on Android for offline access

Tags: android, sqlite, storage, offline

what are the best practices to save content data when the device is offline or when you have already downloaded some content that shouldn't be retrieved from server again?

Is SQLite the best approach to achieve this? If the information that I want to store is retrieved from an API as a JSON should I create a database structure to parse and insert it?

I know that the above are different questions but the purpose is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Sqlite is a bad idea as it is extremely slow and takes up a lot of unnecessary space. When possible serializing objects or using SharedPreferences should be prepared to sqlite (unless of course you have a database structure). For caching and storing data pulled from the internet, I recommend robospice: https://github.com/octo-online/robospice. It's a very well done library, easy to use, and should be used any time you download data from the internet or have a long-running task.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it depends on the type of data you're saving. Sqlite is not always a bad idea. It's slower than storing an array in memory, but if you're handling a 500-entry address book an array is going to be a lot more clunky than a database.

Robospice looks interesting.